# Swift 4: Class coming up as nil and crashing after pushing navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to achieve a transition from one ViewController to the next using pushViewController. I want to execute this when a cell in my CollectionView is tapped. Upon tapping on the cell I would like the information that is being filled in the CollectionView to be displayed on the following ViewController.

I believe I am on the right track to perform this action, but when the ViewController is pushed, and I try and assign the information to a label I get a crash.

**DidSelectRowAtIndexPath**

//This is where I call the function to push the navigation controller with the appropriate information

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var fellow = whoWeAreOptions[indexPath.row]
    handleFullBio(fellow: fellow)
}
```

//This is my function that pushes the ViewController with the class information

```
func handlePush(fellow: WhoWeAreOption) {
    let fellowController = UIViewController()

//Here is the view that is assigned to the bounds of my new ViewController
    let bioView = FullBioView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

//I declare the view's fellow here which should stop the class from being nil
    bioView.fellow = fellow

    fellowController.navigationItem.title = "Full Biography"
    fellowController.view.backgroundColor = .white
    fellowController.view.addSubview(bioView)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(fellowController, animated: true)
}
```

**FullBioView**

//This is the view that is assigned to the ViewControllers bounds which

```
class FullBioView: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

//Here is my class which should have been assigned in the previous function
var fellow: WhoWeAreOption!

let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let text = UILabel()
    text.text = "Username"
    text.font =  UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 24.0)
    text.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22.0)
    text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    text.textColor = Color.blue

    return text
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)              

//I try to assign my class information to a label and the program crashes
    nameLabel.text = fellow.name
}
```

I have toyed with this for a couple days and still have not come up with any reliable results. Is this the appropriate way of going about this? I don't see why my class is appearing as nil when I assigned the class in the handlePush function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try not force unwrapping  fellow, instead of `var fellow: WhoWeAreOption!` use `var fellow: WhoWeAreOption?` .  Best to not force optionals unless you can guarantee their value.

Comment: `bioView.fellow = fellow` where do initialize this fellow? :'D

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately when applying the optional nothing appears.

Comment: Rakesha I assume that the fellow is already initialized considering it was needing to form the CollectionView cell, is this correct?

Comment: Ummm... i do not know. You would know because you would have initialized it somewhere in your code? It's definitely not in the code you shared.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason for crash:

```
fellowController.view.backgroundColor = .white
fellowController.view.addSubview(bioView)
```

The `nil` is `fellowController.view`. You can't access a viewController's view before it's finished loading its view.